# Django ORM: Object is not iterable (Error)

Tags: python, django, forms, typeerror, backend

Can anyone explain why this is iterable:

```
User.objects.all()
```

this is valid and gives me a value (The current user's alias. session is storing the user id):

```
User.objects.get(id = request.session['currentuser']).alias)
```

But this is giving me the error saying it is 'not iterable?':

```
Poke.objects.get(user = User.objects.get(id = request.session['currentuser']).alias)
```

(This code is supposed to get a list of Poke entries where the user column matches the current user's alias.)

Here is the Poke model. It does not use ForeignKeys, as I was having trouble setting two of them without errors.

```
class Poke(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    poker = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pokes = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        app_label = "poke_app"
```

Comment: Please add some more code.. like where are you saving alias ??

Comment: There is something wrong with the brackets of your second code fragment.

Comment: I suppose user parameter passed in Poke model query is a foreign key and you are trying to pass a string for it that's why the error is coming.

Comment: include the `Poke` model in the question

Comment: There are actually no foreign keys. Here is the Poke model:

Comment: alias is an attribute of the User class. Session is storing the id that matches the current user object.

Comment: It is not iterable because `get` returns a single instance. Maybe you need to show where you are iterating and explain why.

Comment: Really? I was told get will return a list of any matching entries...so I could solve this by filtering a Poke.objects.all(), but is there a way to get a list of all matching entries?

Comment: It is `filter` that returns a list (actually a queryset) of matching entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get will retrieve a single object and therefore the result will not be iterable. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get).

Answer (score 0):

Do you see an integer value when you `print(request.session['currentuser'])`?
If you will see a string then you shoud give an integer value 
EX: `userobj = User.objects.get(id=uid)`

Oh sory

```
User.objects.get(id = request.session['currentuser']).alias)
```

You open `(` and closed it after `['currentuser'])` but why you close `)` again after .alias ?